# jQueryUI Autocomplete Binds to First Element Only

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a form that contains a row of inputs. One of those inputs is a jQueryUI autocomplete and each row has a button next to it that clones the row so that additional records can be created. I have the autocomplete set to recognize and bind to the newly created input:

```
$( '.input .my-field' ).on( 'focus', function() {
  var $this = $( this );

  $this.autocomplete({ ... });
});
```

What I'm finding is this:

1. The autocomplete field in the first row works fine.
2. The autocomplete field in the second row works fine *if I didn't enter a value for that field in the first row*.
3. The autocomplete field in the second row doesn't work at all if I *did* enter a value in the first row.

The bottom line is that, if I create all of the rows first, everything works as expected, but this isn't the expected use case. Most folks will enter the first record, click to add another, enter those values, click to add another, rinse, repeat.

I'm still running it down, but I'm burning hours so I'm hoping someone will know what's going on and be able to jump in with a solution that doesn't require hours for me to work out on my own.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but my first thought on this, is you probably need to remove the focus on blur of the first field and that's why it only works if focus isn't given to the first one. Using the off function. I think I could provide better help if you set it up in http://jsfiddle.net/ for me to mess around with.

Comment: I created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ92F/) that confirms the issue. Two questions: why don't you create the `autocomplete` in the moment of cloning, instead of on focus? And why cloning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two additional steps you must perform after cloning an `autocomplete` input before re-creating it:

1. Remove the `aria-haspopup` attribute;
2. Remove the `autocomplete` data.

Just calling `autocomplete("destroy")` won't do, for some reason it destroys the original input instead of the clone. Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ92F/1/). Relevant code below:

```
var clone = $(...)
    .clone(true)
    .removeAttr("aria-haspopup")
    .data("autocomplete",null);
```

Comment: I'll take a look at the details shortly, but a quick question about removing the "autocomplete data". Looks like this is just a `data-` attribute added by the widget? I hadn't noticed that when looking at the generated code for other reasons.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobWilkerson as explained in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/), jQuery stores arbitrary data independently of the `data-` attributes. It can use those to pre-populate the element's `data`, but subsequent changes only reflect on the internal object. I inspected it using [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/), suspected that it prevented `autocomplete` from initializing properly, tested and it worked. But I don't know the specifics about **why** that happens, or why `destroy` behaves so oddly when used on a cloned element.

Comment: Fair enough. I went through and did some web inspector research and you nailed it. Thanks for your help.