# Cloned autocomplete input not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-clone

I have a problem with jQuery function `clone()`. I think the problem is in the `withDataAndEvents` input parameter of this method.

Initially, I'm coding a table that has dynamic rows. I'm adding dynamically rows when clicking on a button put only in the first row. the first row contains initially many inputs fields and combo-boxes. Each field is initalized by an ajax call. And each action on a field leads to the refresh (filtering) on the whole fields of a row. I'm also using autocomplete on input fields.

The first row works perfectly. However, when cloning the  tag:

1. If I did not enter values in the first row, the cloned and first row work fine
2. If I enter a value or values in first row fields and after I clone the , only the first row fields still work. In this case, if I try to change the value of the combo-boxe (which fire a change event for all concerned row fields), the fields of the first row are impacted despite using Ids when changing autocomplete data. Ids of fields, combo-boxes, table rows are dynamically created when clicking on the button to clone the widget.

The code I wrote is too long so I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhcjcegt/) and simplified the case and still have the same problem.

I tried many suggestions that I've found like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593107/jqueryui-autocomplete-binds-to-first-element-only), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664020/jquery-autocomplete-and-clone) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632212/jquery-how-to-clone-autocomplete-fields) in vain :-(
(`data.('autocomplete', null)`, `autocomplete("destroy")` ...)

Do you have ideas about this issue ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Note: Your test example should have `applyAutoComplete2('#myinput2');` (you are selecting by class instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the typo in the test (you are selecting by class instead of the new element by id), the basic problem is you are applying autocomplete before you add it to the DOM.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/87jcw1y0/2/

I just reversed the order of these two lines:

```
$('.body').append(clone);
applyAutoComplete2('#myinput' + inc);
```

The cause... Some plugins use storage data associated with the DOM element, or attach events to ancestors etc. None of these can happen with a disconnected DOM element, so just attach it to the DOM first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Your explanation helped me to find the solution for my issue. Your suggestion is the solution for the case I posted. However, in the real case I've added .autocomplete("destroy") on the element before coloning. I've detached all events on the first row before cloning it and now all the rows work fine... Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think ur asking this
Check in this link http://jsfiddle.net/bsarunmca/87jcw1y0/3/

applyAutoComplete1('#myinput1');

```
$("button").click(function() {
    inc = inc+1;
    $('#myinput1').clone().attr('id','myinput'+inc).appendTo('.add-this');
    $('#myinput'+inc).val('');
    applyAutoComplete2('#myinput'+inc);

});
```

Comment: You need to explain *why* your change fixes the problem (i.e. what the problem was).